# Validating elements named "element" in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have this XML file and I must validate it with a XSD file. I am creating the XSD file but I can't do it.

### A example of my XML file

```
<datos>
<elemento tipoelemento="CABECERA">
    <atributo>
        <nombre>VERSION</nombre>
        <valor>1.0</valor>
    </atributo>
    <atributo>
        <nombre>BRIGADA</nombre>
        <valor>JADSJL</valor>
    </atributo>
    <atributo>
        <nombre>BUZON</nombre>
        <valor>ASDKLFJKA</valor>
    </atributo>
</elemento>
<elemento tipoelemento="INT">
    <atributo>
        <nombre>EQUNR</nombre>
        <valor>9879979797764644</valor>
    </atributo>
    <atributo>
        <nombre>ZDPYC</nombre>
        <valor>N</valor>
    </atributo>
    <atributo>
        <nombre>ZDPATORD</nombre>
        <valor />
    </atributo>
</elemento>
<elemento tipoelemento="EXT">
    <atributo>
        <nombre>zaufnr</nombre>
        <valor>54737674674</valor>
    </atributo>
    <atributo>
        <nombre>zhoras</nombre>
        <valor>6</valor>
    </atributo>
    <atributo>
        <nombre>zpuesto</nombre>
        <valor>sdgfsg</valor>
    </atributo>
</elemento>
```

### My XSD file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
       elementFormDefault="qualified"
       vc:minVersion="1.1">
<xs:element name="datos">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="elemento" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="elemento" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="CABECERA" />
                        <xs:element name="elemento" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="INT" />
                        <xs:element name="elemento" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="EXT" />
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="CABECERA">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="atributo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="VERSION" />
        <xs:element name="atributo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="BRIGADA" />
        <xs:element name="atributo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="BUZON" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="VERSION">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="nombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" fixed="VERSION" />
        <xs:element name="valor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="BRIGADA">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="nombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" fixed="BRIGADA" />
        <xs:element name="valor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="BUZON">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="nombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" fixed="BUZON" />
        <xs:element name="valor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="INT">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="atributo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="EQUNR" />
        <xs:element name="atributo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="ZDPYC" />
        <xs:element name="atributo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="ZDPATORD" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="EQUNR">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="nombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" fixed="EQUNR" />
        <xs:element name="valor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="ZDPYC">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="nombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" fixed="ZDPYC" />
        <xs:element name="valor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="ZDPATORD">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="nombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" fixed="ZDPATORD" />
        <xs:element name="valor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="EXT">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="atributo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="zaufnr" />
        <xs:element name="atributo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="zhoras" />
        <xs:element name="atributo" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="zpuesto" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="zaufnr">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="nombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" fixed="zaufnr" />
        <xs:element name="valor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="zhoras">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="nombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" fixed="zhoras" />
        <xs:element name="valor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="zpuesto">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="nombre" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" fixed="zpuesto" />
        <xs:element name="valor" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

How can I validate the following points in this XSD?

1. Always, the element with `elementtype="CABECERA"` have those same `attribute.name` and this element is required
2. Always, the element with `elementtype="INT"` have those same `attribute.name`, but this element is optional.
3. Always, the element with `elementtype="EXT"` have those same `attribute.name`, but this element is optional.

To create this xsd I have followed this link:
[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27878402/how-to-make-type-depend-on-attribute-value-using-conditional-type-assignment)

but this xsd throws an exception:

cos-element -istent: Error para el tipo 'CABECERA'. Aparecen en el grupo de modelos varios elementos con el nombre 'atributo' y con tipos diferentes.

I can´t abandon this design, I should validate this xml.

could somebody help me?

Comment: The immediate validation error (*Invalid content was found starting with element 'element'. No child element is expected at this point.*) can be easily fixed by changing `xs:choice/@maxOccurs` to be `unbounded`, but you have a [more serious design problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62598564/290085)  that should be addressed.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, the XML design you're trying to represent via XSD is misguided. An element named `element` is a serious sign of a design shortcoming (unless you're writing an XSD for XSD). You really should just abandon this design.

XSD generally expects to be able to differentiate an element's *type* based upon its *name*.  Rather than

```
<element elementtype="HEADER">
  <attribute>
   <name>version</name>
   <value>1.0</value>
  </attribute>
  <attribute>
   <name>imei</name>
   <value>79873489274902475</value>
  </attribute>
</element>
```

your XML would be better designed as this:

```
<HEADER version="1.0" imei="79873489274902475"/>
```

If you insist on the current, excessively meta design, realize that you will not be able to differentiate between same-named elements according to attribute values ***unless you're able to use XSD 1.1***, which supports [Conditional Type Assignment (CTA)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative).

Note, however, that even if you can use CTA, overdoing it as pervasively as would be required to support such an extreme meta design would still be ill-advised.

### Related:

- [How to make type depend on attribute value using Conditional Type Assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27878402/290085)
- [Should I be using XSD 1.1 to build an open standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41147517/290085)

Comment: Sorry @kjhughes. I need to validate an xml with that design, When I take over the task, I will read the links in case it help me.

Comment: If you cannot change the XML design, then you'll need more than XSD 1.0 to validate content models based on attribute values: XSD 1.1 or application code, for example.

Comment: In the coming days, I will take up the task and I'll analyze the xsd 1.1. Thank you for your help, Kjhughes.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't support XSD 1.1, I receive an error about the content of the element wrapping the xs:alternative not matching the expected XSD 1.0 content model ((annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)) How can i fix this?

Comment: Choose one of the following, best alternatives first:  (1) Fix XML design; (2) Switch to processor that supports XSD 1.1; (3) (a) Write application-level validation code, or (b) forego checks requiring CTA.  If you cannot do (1) or (2), choose between (3a) or (3b).

Comment: The Java code doesn't change anything; your options remain as described (1-3).  Please accept and upvote this answer first as having answered usefully at the XSD level, then if you opt for 3a, post a *new question* where you include a Java application validation attempt  (consider using XPath) as a [mcve] and ask how to get past a specific impasse.  Thank you.

Comment: I have edited my question as a minimal reproducible example. Thank you @kjhughes

Comment: Again, you've taken this line of inquiry as far as it can go given your stance on (1-3).  If you wish to ask about 3a, you'll have to post a new question.  I won't extend this exchange any further here.  Good luck.

Comment: Gracias kjhughes but I do not understand what you say, sorry!